# sql server 2008 r2 static ip configuration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a one doubt for SQL Server R2 2008.

In my SQL Server was named one but it has a static IP address. How to assign static IP in SQL Server and also after assigning the IP address, it can be retrieve the data any where in the world?

Comment: Please clarify your question and add details ex. what is named one?

Comment: SQL Server's IP configuration is can be made using Sql Server Configuration Manager. You can find detailed information here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx